# pigeonhole principle on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-geometry

In a disk of radius 10, how can we find all values n such that there are exactly n points in the disk and such that no matter how the n points are arranged, we can draw a disk with radius 1 in the disk of radius 10 such that the small disk does not contain any of the n points? (points may be on the circumference of the small circle but cannot be strictly inside, if that distinction makes a difference)

Comment: I guess you mean a disk and not a circle?

Comment: Yes, I meant disk. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Or equivalently; what is the least amount of disks of radius $1$ required to cover a disk of radius $10$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Check for the biggest square that can fit in the circle.The biggest square has  $\sqrt 200 =14,14$ side.So there are $14*14$ squares of side $1$ in it.Now there are $15*15=225$ vertexs of the squares in the big disk...